# Why IO#lineno doen't alway indicate the next read point for IO#read

Tags: ruby, io

```
f= File.open('path_to_file','w')


f.lineno
#=> 0

f.gets
#=>"this is the content of the first line"

f.lineno

#=>1 # the lineno cooresponse to the next read point of IO#gets

f.rewind

f.lineno

#=>0

f.read

#=>"all the content in the file"

f.lineno

#=>0 # the lineno still is the beginning 

f.read 

#=>"" # but I can't get anyting , it seems like the read point reach to the end of the file, so the f.lineno should be 3, instead of 0
```

Or Is there any other way to know the next read point of IO stream

```
f.lineno

#=>0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Ruby IO docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html), `lineno` doesn't tell you the position in the stream. Rather, it tells you how many times gets has been called. As the `read` function doesn't use `gets`, the `lineno` value doesn't change.

What you probably want is is `pos`, which tells you the current offset in the file in bytes. You can also set `pos` to jump to a different spot in the file.